# concatenate problems with concat function

Tags: javascript

In this case of concat() function, i don't get why the value of the length property is not concatenated to array. Also when i change the value of length property to some random value, the first two properties are ignored as well when i concatenate them.
1st case:

```
let arr = [1, 2];

let arrayLike = {
  0: "something",
  1: "else",
  [Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]: true,
  length: 2
};

alert( arr.concat(arrayLike) ); // 1,2,something,else
```

2nd case:

```
let arr = [1, 2];

let arrayLike = {
  0: "something",
  1: "else",
  [Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]: true,
  length: "random",
};

console.log( arr.concat(arrayLike) ); // 1,2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `arrayLike` object is sort of mimicking being an array like `arr`. So if you're treating it like a normal array, then why would you expect the value of `length` to be counted as a value in the array?

In your actual array, `arr`, you would have `arr.length == 2`. But `2` is not a value in the array, it just tells you how many values are in the array (two values, `1` and `2`). This is how JavaScript knows how many values to look for. If you were to set `arr.length = 1`, suddenly JavaScript would only show one value instead of two. See here:

```js
let arr = [1, 2];
console.log(arr); //[1, 2]

arr.length = 1;
console.log(arr) //[1]
```

Similarly, your `length: 2` property in your `arrayLike` object is being used to represent an array with 2 elements. If you set it to something that isn't a number, JavaScript no longer knows how many values could be in the "array", so it apparently simply counts it as 0 - an empty array.

Comment: Thanks. So what i understood from your answer is, if i'm to use concatenate an object to an array, i have to define the length of object, right?

Comment: @fatihthebach Depends entirely what your goal here is. This is some odd code, why not simply use a proper array for the concat instead of this "fake" one?

Comment: No, what i mean is that i wonder if i have to define length of the object that i am going to concat to that particular array. Sorry if i can't explain myself clearly..

Comment: @fatihthebach Smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If your goal is to *put each property value of an object into an array*, you ought to use `Object.values(obj)` to get an array of values in the object, which can then be concatenated. You will only need to define the length of the object if you insist on making a fake "array-like" object where property keys are all integers from 0-N.